# inserta valor concatenado en mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

buenas tardes, tengo en una página un formulario de donde se obtiene valores, los cuales a través de un archivo los adjunto a la base de datos, pues bien ahora quiero que el valor de un campo me lo concatene con una cadena fija y dos datos variables, ¿cómo lo incluyo en el código?

campo que quiero calcualar: marcas
obtiene los datos de la siguiente cadena: http://www.mipagina/marca/

y los valores que quiero concatenar son los que tengo en las variables iniciales y color, de tal forma que debe que debe quedar asi el valor que deberá insertarse en la tabla: http://www.mipagina/marca/pj/#0000ff

El codigo que tengo y que si funciona es el siguiente, pero ahi toma los valores del formulario

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `stv_t_instaladores`
            (
            `nombre_completo`,
            marca,
            estatus,
            `iniciales`,
            `colorx`
            )
            VALUES
            (
            '$_POST[nombre_completo]',
            '$_POST[marca]',
            '$_POST[estatus]',
            '$_POST[iniciales]',
            '$_POST[colorx]'
            );";
```

Espero haberme dado a entender,grcias.

Comment: El código que compartes parece vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías mirar lo que es y cómo evitarlos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hijo, primero que nada no necesitas poner en las columnas separadas por comillas en la citación, ademas cada ves que incluyes algo que venga por post(un array) puedes concatenarlo en el string de la siguiente forma:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO stv_t_instaladores
            (
            nombre_completo,
            marca,
            estatus,
            iniciales,
            colorx
            )
            VALUES
            (
            '".$_POST[nombre_completo]."',
            '".$_POST[marca]."',
            '".$_POST[estatus]."',
            '".$_POST[iniciales]."',
            '".$_POST[colorx]."'
            );";
```

otra manera de hacerlo mediante Injeccion de variables al string puede ser:

```
#1 pasar los valores del post a variables:
$nombre_completo = $_POST[nombre_completo];
$marca= $_POST[marca];
$estatus= $_POST[estatus];
$iniciales= $_POST[iniciales];
$colorx= $_POST[colorx];

# y luego concatenarlo:

    $sql = "INSERT INTO stv_t_instaladores
                (
                nombre_completo,
                marca,
                estatus,
                iniciales,
                colorx
                )
                VALUES
                (
                '$nombre_completo',
                '$marca',
                '$estatus',
                '$iniciales',
                '$colorx'
                );";
```

Citando que todo es texto, o descimales puede he colocado los valores entre comilla simples ('), en tal caso quieras ver la cadena solo debes ponerle un echo delante de la variable.

```
echo $sql;
```

**OJO:** 
El código tal y como lo tienes ahora es vulnerable de Inyección SQL.
Estas programando de la manera mas insegura que hay, te recomiendo pasarte a PDO y hacer Bind de los valores [Link](https://github.com/lincanbin/PHP-PDO-MySQL-Class)

Answer (score 0):

Con esto debería ser suficiente

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `stv_t_instaladores`
        (
            `nombre_completo`,
            marca,
            estatus,
            `iniciales`,
            `colorx`,
            `marcas`
        )
        VALUES
        (
            '$_POST[nombre_completo]',
            '$_POST[marca]',
            '$_POST[estatus]',
            '$_POST[iniciales]',
            '$_POST[colorx]',
            '" . $_POST[iniciales] . $_POST[colorx] . "'
        );";
```

Comment: tengo que incluir otro campo que se llama marcas y en el codigo que hiciste favor de agragar como incluyo el texto fijo antes de iniciales y colorx?

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente quiero advertir, como se ha dicho ya en algún comentario, **que el código tal y como lo tienes ahora es vulnerable de [Inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)**.

Es una mala práctica construir cadenas SQL **completas**, ya que dicha cadena puede ser modificada maliciosamente e incluir código de borrado de tablas, o consultas para obtener claves de usuarios, etc.

Como respuesta al núcleo de tu pregunta, podrías obtener el contenido de tu URL de forma dinámica usando [**`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`**](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php), que sirve para obtener la URI usada para acceder a la página. En este caso devolverá: `/marca/pj/#0000ff`, luego puedes obtener cada parte usando [**`explode`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php).

Ejemplo:

<kbd>[**VER DEMO**](http://rextester.com/FTLE56984)</kbd>

```
<?php 

/*
    * Rextester no permite usar $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    * Creamos el resultado que daría de forma manual
    * En tu servidor debería funcionar de forma dinámica con esta línea:
    * $miURL=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
*/

    $miURL=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    // Creamos un arreglo usando el separador /
    $arrURL= explode('/', $miURL);

    // Leemos e imprimimos cada parte
    $marca=$arrURL[1];
    $inicial=$arrURL[2];
    $color=$arrURL[3];

    echo $marca."\n";
    echo $inicial."\n";
    echo $color."\n";

?>
```

**Resultado**

```
marca
pj
#0000ff
```

El siguiente paso sería hacer el `INSERT`, pero aplicando para ello consultas preparadas.